# Number Of ACE of a File - There is only 9 Members in Security Tab of File Property but it returns 13 ACE from ACL

Tags: c++, winapi, acl

void main() {

```
PSID UserSID = NULL;
PSID GroupSID = NULL;
//PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *SD = new PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, sizeof(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR));
PACL pDACL ;
ULONG Count = NULL;
PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_W* pExplicitEntries = new PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_W;


string input, ext = "";
wcout << "Enter the location : " << endl;
std::getline(cin, input);
LPCSTR file = input.c_str();

HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        cout << "Access Denied : System Files" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "Path Name Not Found" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "File Not Found" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }
}
cout << GetLastError() << endl;

if ((GetSecurityInfo(hFile,SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pDACL, NULL, &SD)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "Number of ACE : " << pDACL->AceCount << endl;  
    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < pDACL->AceCount; i++)
{
    PACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE AceItem;
    ACE_HEADER* AceHdr = NULL;
    if (GetAce(pDACL, i, (LPVOID*)&AceItem) && GetAce(pDACL, i, (LPVOID*)&AceHdr))
    {
        TCHAR AccountBuff[80];
        TCHAR DomainBuff[80];
        DWORD AccountBufflength = 40;
        DWORD DomainBufflength = 40;
        PSID_NAME_USE peUse = new SID_NAME_USE;
        PSID Sid = &AceItem->SidStart;

        LookupAccountSidW(NULL, Sid, AccountBuff, &AccountBufflength, DomainBuff, &DomainBufflength,peUse);

        wcout << "\n----- " << AccountBuff << " @ " << DomainBuff << " -----\n" << endl;

        wcout << "AceType : " << AceHdr->AceType << " " << "Ace Flag : " << AceHdr->AceFlags << "\n" << endl;

        DisplayAccessMask(AceItem->Mask);

    }
    else
    {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
}
```

}`

How to get the correct number of ACE in the security tab of a file property ?
There is only 9 Members in Security Tab of File Property but the Access Control List consist of 13 ACE.
Can anyone tell me how can i get the users listed in the security tab `->`advanced and their file permission...

Comment: What are the "extra" entries? What do they represent? Have you analysed them? Can you just filter them out?

Comment: Actually, it is repeating some of the username twice with different ACE Flag.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I filter those extra 
ACE

Comment: Use `if` and `continue`?

Comment: What is the condition i need to give ?

Answer (score 0):

> An ACE contains a set of access rights and a security identifier (SID)
> that identifies a trustee for whom the rights are allowed, denied, or
> audited.

ACE is access control entry, it not one-to-one correspondent to users and groups.

Each ACE in an access control list (ACL) applies to one trustee. But for one trustee, there may be multiple ACEs, like below, the same Administrators group has two ACEs, one is type of deny and another is type of allow:

[image]

> Can anyone tell me how can i get the users listed in the security tab
> ->advanced and their file permission...

`GetSecurityInfo` does give me consistent number to permission entries at file properties -> secutiry -> advanced.

---

**Update:**

> Number Of ACE of a File - There is only 9 Members in Security Tab of
> File Property but it returns 13 ACE from ACL

It may happen that you find there is a difference between **ACEs entries number** (returned returned by `GetSecurityInfo()` and `GetAce()`) and **the permission entries number** (in the advanced security tab for folders).

Take folder `C:/program files` as an example. There are 9 permissions entries show in the advanced security tab for this folder as below.

[image]

However you may get 13 ACE entries using `GetSecurityInfo()` and `GetAce()`.

**It is expected because there is no 1:1 mapping between the ACE entry and the permission entry in the dialog.**

File explorer applies some rules in order for displaying permission entries friendly to users. For example, there are two ACE entries, one is the full control for this folder and another is full control for subfolders, both of them for same user: TrustedInstaller. These two ACEs are merged into one displayed.

[image]

Comment: GetSecurityInfo gives me A List of ACE as DACL ... but DACL consist of ACE which are not listed in the Advanced Security Tab ...Try Running the code ....

Comment: Use C:/program files as input

Comment: @RubanThilak Yes, for me, folders result in more ACEs than listed in the Advanced Security Tab but files work. Could you have a check?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly happens for me also, works fine with file but not with folders.
can you help me with this issue ? please tell any other ways to get all the users and permission in the advanced security tab for folders

Comment: @RubanThilak Thanks for your confirmation. For folders I'll do a further investigation and update to you ASAP.

Comment: Thank You @Rita Han - MSFT .... Looking forward for possible reply

Comment: @RubanThilak Sorry for the delay. The data returned by `GetSecurityInfo()` and `GetAce()` are actually the raw data entries in the `ACL` for the specific object. However, the entries you observed in the security settings dialog are the arranged data based on the raw `ACE` data, and there is no 1:1 mapping between the raw `ACE` entry and the permission entry in the dialog. So you may find these two counts are not same. Using WINAPI you already get all of data about users and permissions which is more than or equal to the ones in the advanced security tab for folders.